# Passing an array to javascript in Tapestry

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, tapestry

In my Tapestry template, I have an array of RoutePoint objects (which consist of a latitude and a longitude value) and I want to pass them to javascript, so that the [line of points can
be displayed on a map.](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines) Has anyone an idea how to do it?

Comment: Convert the list to a JSON string and drop it into the page inside a `<script>` block, where it'd be assigned to a JavaScript variable (or passed to a function, or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat like @Pointy noted but Tapestry has a more elegant way of initializing scripts that inlining it into a `<script>` tag. Here is my GoogleMap component code showing how I add a map to my Tapestry page printing a pointer on an address. For how to add multiple connecting with a line check out the google maps API.

In your Tapestry page:

```
@BeginRender
void doBeginRender(MarkupWriter writer) {

    String clientId = javaScriptSupport.allocateClientId(componentResources);
    String mapsScripURL = (request.isSecure()) ? SECURE_GOOGLE_MAPS_SCRIPT_URL : GOOGLE_MAPS_SCRIPT_URL;
    javaScriptSupport.importJavaScriptLibrary(mapsScripURL);


    writer.element("div", "id", clientId, "class", "googleMapCanvas " + clientId);
        writer.end();

    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
    parameters.put("mapCanvasId", clientId);
    parameters.put("geoAddress", geoAddress);
    javaScriptSupport.addInitializerCall("GoogleMap", parameters);
}
```

Add a javascript file to your page/component using `@Import(library = {"GoogleMap.js"})` where the GoogleMap.js looks somewhat like (I use prototype.js):

```
Tapestry.Initializer.GoogleMap = function (parameters) {
new GoogleMap(parameters);
};

var GoogleMap = { };
GoogleMap = Class.create({
initialize:function(parameters) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': parameters.geoAddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 11,
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(parameters.mapCanvasId), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
    });
}
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a "GoogleMapComponent" and added your "BeginRender" Method and imported the JavaScript part. However, I couldn't figure out what to write in the template file. I tried it with `<t:googleMapComponent style="width:100%; height:400px"></t:googleMapComponent>` but it doesn't show a map.

Comment: This component does not need a template as the begin render prints out the DOM elements for you. See the part: `writer.element("div", "id", clientId, "class", "googleMapCanvas " + clientId); writer.end();` Just add the code you show here in your comment to the page you want to put the map on and it should work. And if that does not work, check for js errors.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was a bit misleading. I talked about the template of the page not of the component. When I change the `writer.element("div", "id", clientId, "class", "googleMapCanvas " + clientId);` to `writer.element("div", "id", clientId, "class", "googleMapCanvas " + clientId, "style","width:100%; height:400px" );` it works perfect. But when I add `style="width:100%; height:400px"` to `<t:googleMapComponent ></t:googleMapComponent>` it is just ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: Annotate your component with @SupportsInformalParameters. Have a look at http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/SupportsInformalParameters.html

Comment: Yes, that was the missing part, and I now got all working. Thanks again.